# Виртуальный список с разной высотой элементов | REACT

Tags: reactjs, list

Знает кто-то, как сделать правильный виртуальный список с разной высотой элементов? react-window требует высоты элеметов, но смысл в том, что я могу узнать её только после рендера элемента.

Но мои элементы всегда имеют разную высоту и довольно тяжелы, чтобы рендерить их только для получения высоты.

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Я пытался через ref возвращать высоту, но в такой случае нужно ждать 5-6 секунд, прежде чем весь список отрендерится и перестанет дергаться из-за изменяющегося стейта, который содержит эти самые высоты.

Код не прикреплял, так как не вижу в этом смысла. Вопрос понятен и без него.

Answer (score 1):

#### Проблема

Библиотеки `react-virtualized` и `react-window` отвратительно реализуют виртуализацию, так как используют компонент высшего порядка `<AutoSizer />`. Последний использует функцию для обновления списка потомков, поэтому не только нагружает планировщик проверкой изменения `height` и `width`, но и ломает `change detection` композиции `props` в коде прикладного программиста

Однако если посмотреть на тот же [Slack](https://slack.com/) или [Discord](https://discord.com/), там сообщения в чатах явно виртуализируются, так как при скролле показываются с задержкой. Видимо, в их кодовой базе виртуализация с динамической высотой блоков таки есть...

**Вывод:**

1. Нужно писать свою виртуализацию. Это как базовый компонент строк в C++
2. Нужно делать интероп над ванильным JavaScript кодом, так как этот код высоконагружен и абстракция `react` для него слишком тормозная

#### Решение проблемы

> Разумеется, вы не первый, кто наткнулся на проблему, поэтому, делюсь своим решением. [Посмотреть демо можно по ссылке](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-declarative-virtualview-g66jr8)

```js
import React from "react";

import { VirtualView } from "react-declarative";

import mock from "./mock";

export const App = () => (
  <VirtualView
    sx={{
      height: "100vh",
      width: "100vw"
    }}
  >
    {mock.map(({ id, content }, idx) => (
      <div key={id}>
        <p>
          <b>Item {idx + 1}</b>
        </p>
        <span>{content || "Content empty"}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </VirtualView>
);

export default App;
```

[image: screenshot]

[Код компонента на GitHub](https://github.com/react-declarative/react-declarative/blob/dcf859e9e3a124ce0a7a7bc906002c53eef7b6e0/src/components/VirtualView/VirtualView.tsx)

P.S. Если собираетесь виртуализировать список компонентов, [не забудьте применить forwardRef](https://github.com/react-declarative/react-declarative/blob/dcf859e9e3a124ce0a7a7bc906002c53eef7b6e0/src/components/Grid/components/ContentRow.tsx#L94), чтобы `<VirtualList />` смог достучаться до размеров элемента DOM древа